# Can you reset a CSS element to refer to absolute zero within a relative element

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

This is a rather random problem.  I'm using CSS3Pie to handle CSS3 compatibility in IE, but I've run into a snag.  With PIE in a lot of cases you need to use position:relative for it to work properly in IE.

This becomes an issue when I use it on containing wrappers, as it then moves in the zero reference inside of the layout.  The software we use for mapping on our sites uses an absolute position of the top left corner of the browser as its point of reference for calculating positioning.  Ideally our software would be more flexible and not reliant on an absolute position like that, but that's probably not going to change anytime soon.

So getting to my question, is it possible to somehow take an element out of the flow of the layout and refer back to the original 0,0 top left position while being contained within a relatively positioned object?  I thought maybe z-index might work, but it doesn't make the element refer back to absolute 0,0.

The most simple workaround is to not apply PIE to my wrappers, but then that also removes rounded corners and dropshadows from my layout wrapper.  That isn't the end of the world, but ideally I'd like to come up with a solution.

Comment: Is a javascript/jquery solution acceptable?

Comment: Is it possible to control where in the DOM the absolutely positioned elements show up? I assume they're pop-ups or something, correct? If you move the markup outside of the relatively positioned div, say just before the close of the body tag, you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to avoid javascript, but with that said we do load the jquery library already on our sites by default.

Comment: You'd like to avoid javascript, but whole CSS3PIE is based on javascript. That's weird.

Comment: Tom, you are correct with that.  It's more that our whole platform is kind of a rats nest of javascript at times, so I typically like to steer clear of adding more of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var el = $('#absolute'); // element we want to work with
    el.clone().appendTo('body'); // clone and append to body
    el.remove(); // remove element
});
```

This is a little improvement of **Wilson Page**'s code. Tested so far only on `localhost`, but it did the trick. Tested with IE6/7/8 + CSS3PIE enabled.

Wanted to put this up on public webserver, but it turns out they haven't enabled `*.htc` support, and when using it with `PIE.php` (the script provided with PIE) — it didn't work.

Will do some more testing later on when I get back to office and start pushing system admins to enable `*.htc` support on server. *hehe*

And, I fully tested **Sebastian Patane Masue**'s script, it did the job! +1 @ *Sebastian*.

P.S. With fully I mean with CSS3PIE enabled and properties added to actual style.

EDIT: Just gave this a one more try, and the results are pretty annoying. It works on localhost flawlessly, but is pretty bugged when viewing it remotely. Have no idea what is causing that...

Comment: I can confirm this code does work on my site.  Works well with CSS3PIE.  Great work!

Comment: Oh, that actually surprises me. Looks like I'll have to poke my sysadmins even more, to get this working perfectly on my own host too. ^^,

Answer (score 1):

I think JS/jQuery is required for this:

try something like:

```
var el = $('#element');

$('body').append(el);
el.remove();
```

Hope this is an acceptable fix,

W.

Comment: Gave that a whirl and had no luck.  So what is it that this function is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Great Question: i think it might be impossible without js.

this is a jQuery workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/hSh25/

it takes the left and top values of the relatively positioned element and subtracts them from the absolute one, in effect returing the absolute one to the origin point.

so, given

```
<div id="relative">
relative
  <div id="absolute">
     absolute;
 </div>
```

this calculates how to get back to 0 before adding left and top values for the positioned div.

```
var relativeLeft = $('#relative').css('left');
var absoluteLeft =  $('#absolute').css('left');
var returnToOriginLeft = (parseInt(absoluteLeft) - parseInt(relativeLeft)) + 'px';
var relativeTop = $('#relative').css('top');
var absoluteTop =  $('#absolute').css('top');
var returnToOriginTop = (parseInt(absoluteTop) - parseInt(relativeTop)) + 'px';
$('#absolute').css('left', returnToOriginLeft);
$('#absolute').css('top', returnToOriginTop);
```

you'll have to get more specific in your actual site (i imagine there's a bunch of relatively positioned divs there).Please let me know if its a workable solution for CSS3PIE, as i plan to use it myself in a project soon.

*note:* Javascript is not my strong point, i suspect that there is a more elegant way of writing the statement above.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I will have to give it a spin tomorrow, it looks like it'll do what I need it to do.

Comment: @jamEs: great, pleas let us know if its a viable solution with CSS3Pie.